# How to print a newline in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

I want to print out a newline-character in a string or achieve a wordwrap in any way. The C-style escape sequence `\n` does not seem to work!
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to concatenate the string parts with `String cr` or `Character cr`.

Full example:

```
Transcript show: 'First line', String cr, 'Second line'.
```

This will print following into the Transcript window:

```
First line
Second line
```

Comment: You can also send `#cr` message directly to Transcript or stream to simplify your job

Comment: This is a nice illustration of Smalltalk's uniformity - sending messages to objects instead of special magical codes embedded in the string